# My Spring app running on Docker for Windows crashes due to an UnknownHostException

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to run a Spring app in a Docker container, but it keeps crashing due to an UnknownHostException caused by an image named "some-postgres". I had downloaded the official Postgres Docker image at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres, and followed the setup instructions, and I created an image called "some-postgres". At some point, I set `spring.datasource.url` in my applications.properties to `jdbc:postgresql://some-postgres:5432/docker_atm`, and now, no matter what I use as my data source URL, and regardless of whether there's any usages of "some-postgres" in my project, I keep getting this error stacktrace:

```
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114821300Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114843600Z  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114847500Z  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114850500Z  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114853100Z  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114855800Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114858400Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114861100Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114863800Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114866500Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114869200Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114871900Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114874600Z  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114877400Z  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114884400Z  at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114887400Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114890300Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114893000Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114896100Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114898900Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114904900Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114908000Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:104) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114911100Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114915000Z  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114919000Z  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114922700Z  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114927000Z  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) [hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114931700Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114936200Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114940600Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) [spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114944800Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114949200Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114953900Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114958200Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114962100Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114965500Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114968300Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114975000Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114978400Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114982400Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114985200Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114988100Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114991100Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114993800Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114996500Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.114999200Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115001900Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115004500Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115007100Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115009800Z  at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MyApplication.main(DockerAtmApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115012400Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115015400Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115019000Z  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115022800Z  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115026200Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115030000Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115033800Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115037700Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:na]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115040500Z Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: some-postgres
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115046600Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115053400Z  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115056900Z  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115059500Z  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115062000Z  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115064800Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115067600Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115070400Z  ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

And here's my docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password!
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" #maps the host's port 5432 to the container's port 5432
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin: #access this on localhost:5050
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

I've tried a Gradle refresh, I've tried rebuilding the whole project, I've tried `docker-compose build --no-cache`, **I've even tried the "nuclear option" of `docker system prune`**, but no matter what, this one Docker image keeps haunting my code.

EDIT: Here's the application.properties file I'm using:

```
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/docker_atm
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password!

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

#Database initialisation - change to "validate" when in production
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yml under the following part

```
postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
```

you have named the database service as postgres. So by default docker will expose a host as ...postgres...

But from `Spring-boot` application it seems you try to connect to host `some-postgres`.

```
2022-10-04T10:56:32.115040500Z Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: some-postgres
```

The configuration that spring boot app has as you mention is `jdbc:postgresql://some-postgres:5432/docker_atm`

So to fix the situation you have 2 options:

1. change the spring boot configuration into  `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/docker_atm`
2. keep the existing spring boot configuration url property `jdbc:postgresql://some-postgres:5432/docker_atm` and change the `docker-compose.yml` into

   ```
   some-postgres:
        container_name: postgres
        image: postgres
   ```

   so that the host available becomes the `some-postgres`.

**Edit**:
As to provide a clear specific solution please do the following.

Modify your compose.yml with the following

```
some-postgres: <---------------------
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: docker_atm  <------------- 
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password!
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" #maps the host's port 5432 to the container's port 5432
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

    .....
```

You have also forgot to declare in your docker the database name for your postgresql instance.

Then your spring boot application property should be

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://some-postgres:5432/docker_atm
```

Rebuild the docker image and the jar for the application and repackage and redeploy and it shall work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I tried both of them and I'm still getting `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: some-postgres`.

Comment: @CiaranC94 whatever of 2 approaches you take you need to build either again the docker container or build the jar application that contains the property

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions, and neither worked. If I try using "localhost" in my properties file, I just get `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`.

Comment: @CiaranC94 do you use docker desktop?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: then localhost will not work. Share what exactly you tried with specific application property and specific compose.yml

Comment: I've added my .properties file to my post. I've tried using `postgres` and `some-postgres` instead of `localhost` as my data source URL, and none of them work.